# Validation of prediction interval for count data

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, prediction, count-data, validation

I have developed a random-effects (frailty) survival model for repeated events which enables calculating individual-specific mean and prediction interval for the cumulative incidence (rate) of future events for a given individual. I am trying to internally and externally validate the prediction interval in terms of its coverage probability. However, this seems to be a bit complicated for count data because the prediction interval is about the individual-specific rate of events (real values) but the the observed outcomes are counts (integer values). I can transform the observed counts of events into their rates but a sizeable proportion of the sample who has zero events will have a zero observed rate which is always outside of the prediction interval for rate (which is strictly positive).